# python2.7: Is it possible to determine whether __init__ was called from a subclass or just normally?

Tags: python, class, subclass, super

I have two classes

```
class A()

class B(A)
```

Sometimes class A is instantiated normally, and sometimes via class B with

```
super(B, self).__init__()
```

Is it possible to determine whether Class A's init method was called from B or from outside?

Comment: You can test whether `self` is an instance of `B`. It would normally be an indication that you're approaching something wrong.

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: This shouldn't be class `A`'s matter...

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `type(self)` to `A`:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        if type(self) == A:
            print('From A')

        else:
            print('From elsewhere')

class B(A):
    pass

A()
B()
```

Output:

```
From A
From elsewhere
```

This is one of the only times you want `type` over `isinstance`, though I'm not sure *why* you want to do this in the first place.

Comment: I want to add them to a list, and was going to do it in the constructor, but only want to add the subclass if the superclass is not added.